# Outlook MAPI in C++ application: Get SMTP address (PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) after a IMAPITABLE restrict

Tags: outlook, mapi

I have a PR_ANR_W restriction in my MAPI application, to find users that match a text pattern:

```
enum
{
    abPR_DISPLAY_NAME,
    abrPR_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    abPropTagToCompare,
    abNUM_COLS
};

const SizedSPropTagArray(abNUM_COLS, abCols) =
{
    abNUM_COLS,
    PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W,
    PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W,
    PropTagToCompare
};

LPSRestriction lpSRes = nullptr;
CreateANRRestriction(PR_ANR_W, szName, nullptr, &lpSRes); // szName = "diego"
pIMAPITABLE->SetColumns(LPSPropTagArray(&abCols), TBL_BATCH);
pIMAPITABLE->Restrict(lpSRes, NULL);

LPSRowSet pRows = nullptr;
pIMAPITABLE->QueryRows(1, NULL, &pRows);

pRows->aRow->lpProps[abPR_DISPLAY_NAME].Value.lpszW   // --> Diego Doñate
pRows->aRow->lpProps[abrPR_EMAIL_ADDRESS].Value.lpszW // --> /o=Company/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=diego.dnate@company.com
```

PR_DISPLAY_NAME_W & PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W are in "MAPITags.h"

but there I can not find PR_SMTP_ADDRESS, to get in my case: diego.donate@company.com (not the / cn value from previous string))

How can I get the SMTP address of theses contacts?

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Answer (score 0):

I found it, i had to use the Hex value for PR_SMTP_ADDRESS in SizedSPropTagArray:

PROP_TAG(PT_UNICODE,    0x39FE)